# Javascript xpath pointer - dialog box won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I have a task where I need to point with my mouse on an element in the page, and according to the pointed xpath a popup should appear and the user should classify this xpath. The code is provided below.

I use JQuery. The problem is after I point to an element, the dialog doesn't close. What is the problem with my code?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Xpath classification</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

        function getXPath(element) {
            var xpath = "";
            for (; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode) {
                var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
                id > 1 ? (id = "[" + id + "]") : (id = "");
                xpath = "/" + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
            }
            return xpath;
        }

        $(document).click(function (event) {
            popup(event);
        });


        function popup(event) {
            var xpath = getXPath(event.target);

            $("<div></div>").dialog({
                width: 340,
                modal: true,
                open: function () {
                    $(this).html("The xpath type of " + xpath + " is:");
                },
                buttons: {
                    "It's type A element": function () {
                        /* Do some code of type A elements...
                         * ...
                         */
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "It's type B element": function () {
                        /* Do some code of type A elements...
                         * ...
                         */
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        ;
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>This is a header element</h1>
    <p>This is an element and a link: <a href="http://example.com">the link</a>.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle for that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the click event of choosing from the dialog immediately fired another click event on the document, preventing effectively from the dialog to close. I've changed the event of `click` to `dblclick`, i.e., double click. It's a workaround which is sufficient for me, so the double click won't fire another click event.